# Google Chrome Removing Semantic UI Duplicate Classes

Tags: angular, google-chrome, semantic-ui

**UPDATE 2**

It certainly seems to be an issue with using the Class Property binding along with an element that has duplicate class names. We ended up refactoring our code to apply a class the the parent element that then sends styles down to the children.

**UPDATE 1**

So I did just realize that removing the Class Property binding tags fixes the issue. But I need them to make my application operate correctly. Which leads me to think that this might be a combination of Angular and Chrome type issue. I'll investigate further...

**ORIGINAL POST**

I don't know why, but at some point yesterday google chrome began removing "wide" classes beyond the first instance from my HTML elements. For example:

```
<div id="contentContainer" class="three wide mobile twelve wide tablet thirteen wide computer column" [class.content-full-screen]="!sidebarVisibility">
```

Becomes this:

```
<div id="contentContainer" class="three wide mobile twelve tablet thirteen computer column" [class.content-full-screen]="!sidebarVisibility">
```

I am building an Angular application with a vanilla build of semantic. Not using any of the angular specific libraries. It has been happening on multiple computers, with the only common factor being Chrome. Oddly Firefox and Safari seem to work just fine.

I am wondering if anyone knows if Chrome did an update or something like that. Or if anyone knows why all of the sudden the code is being interpreted differently.

Comment: question question: why do you need duplicates?

Comment: Short answer: It's how semantic works, it uses a "<number> wide <device>" syntax to define responsive breakpoints.

Comment: Thx, learned something today :)

Comment: [Apijay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2547985/apijay) went through the effort to reproduce the issue [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uf6mv1?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) for those interested in taking a look.